# Selling of shares without consent

Tags: stocks

Can my shares be sold without my consent in case I defaulted in making payment for the stock I bought 3 days before!

Comment: If you defaulted making payment, then they aren't your shares.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/nn/articles/Stock-Settlement-Why-You-Need-to-Understand-the-T-3-Timeline

Answer (score 4):

No sales can happen without your consent.  However, **you gave your consent for this when you signed your broker agreement**.  Read the fine print and it will probably address this question specifically.

The reason your broker is allowing you to buy things before paying for them is that you have an agreement with them that makes them feel comfortable selling it back and keeping the money if you somehow end up without the ability to pay.